# Query membership of group on date with open-ended memberships

Tags: mysql

Given the following table structure for tracking membership of given groups:

```
+----+----------+----------------+--------------+  
| id | group_id | in_group_begin | in_group_end |  
+----+----------+----------------+--------------+  
|  1 |       10 | 2019-01-01     | 2019-02-01   |  
|  1 |       11 | 2019-02-02     | 2019-03-01   |  
|  1 |       12 | 2019-03-01     | NULL         |  
|  2 |       10 | 2019-01-01     | NULL         |  
+----+----------+----------------+--------------+
```

(Where `in_group_end` being NULL signifies this is their current group)

How would I form a query that would tell me, for example, what `group_id` each member was associated with on a given date?

`... in_group_end IS NULL` will give me their current group, not necessarily the group they were in
`... in_group_end IS NULL OR in_group_end >= '{$date_str}'` could give me multiple options

Ideally I would like something I can use in a joined query, e.g. with a table storing a persons name, address, etc. from which I expect only one row back.

Would some kind of `IF` stmt in the JOIN do it? or `GROUP` in a sub-query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following logic, which would find all matches for `2019-01-15`:

```
SELECT group_id
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    '2019-01-15' >= in_group_begin AND
    ('2019-01-15' <= in_group_end OR in_group_end IS NULL);
```

The `WHERE` clause considers an input date a match if it lies in between the start and end dates *or* it is greater than the start date and there is no end date.  Also, the `WHERE` clause as written can make use of an index.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you want to search for a date `2019-01-03`.

```
SELECT
    id,
    group_id
FROM membership
WHERE '2019-01-03' BETWEEN in_group_begin AND IFNULL(in_group_end, CURRENT_DATE);
```

If you have another `users` table which stores details of users and `id` of that table is used in `membership` table using `id` field. You can do following query.

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    u.name,
    u.address,
    m.group_id
FROM users u
INNER JOIN membership m ON u.id = m.id
WHERE '2019-01-03' BETWEEN in_group_begin AND IFNULL(in_group_end, CURRENT_DATE);
```

Comment: Thanks Jitendra, I went with Tim, as he was first, but I figured there'd be a use for `IF`/`IFNULL` somewhere!

Comment: Not a problem, Happy to help.:)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is a table `users` from which you want the user's details returned, join it to your table `tablename` like this:

```
select u.*, t.group_id
from users u inner join (
  select 
    id, group_id, in_group_begin, 
    coalesce(in_group_end, current_date) in_group_end 
  from tablename
) t on t.id = u.id and @date between t.in_group_begin and t.in_group_end
```

Replace `@date` with the date you search for.

Comment: Thanks forpas - I was not familiar with coalesce, and I will be able to play around with it now!